# Unresolved reference: awaitMap()

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Мне нужно динамически добавлять polylines в гугл карты, используя jetpack compose.Я следовал следующим инструкциям: "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-polylines-on-google-maps-in-android-using-jetpack-compose/". Но я получаю ошибку в строке `val map = mapView.awaitMap()` в MainActivity.kt Unresolved reference: awaitMap(). Что не так с моим кодом. В AndroidManifest.xml добавил все необходимые разрешения и meta-data.

MapUtils.kt

```
package com.example.testappimport android.os.Bundle
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
            id = R.id.map
        }
    }
    val lifecycleObserver = rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }
    return mapView
}

@Composable
fun rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver = remember(mapView) {
    LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when(event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onCreate(Bundle())
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import com.example.testapp.ui.theme.TestAppTheme
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.maps.android.compose.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            TestAppTheme {
                mapUI(LocalContext.current)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
        Log.d("AppTag", "entered")
    }
}

@Composable
fun mapUI(context: Context) {
    val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.White)) {
        AndroidView({ mapView }) { mapView ->
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                val map = mapView.awaitMap()
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(54.0943, 28.3215), 12f))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module), dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.4'

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
```

layout_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Подключите зависимость [`com.google.maps.android:maps-ktx`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/ktx). Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или задайте его на английском SO.

Comment: Понял, хорошо. Спасибо